# Python CGI Script Error: End of script output before headers

Tags: python, windows, apache, xampp

I'm getting an internal server error (500 err) "End of script output before headers" trying to run a cgi using

- XAMPP Apache on Windows
- Python 3.3
- Notepad++ with UNIX Style (\n) newline chars

My script reads as follows

```
#!"C:\Python33\python.exe"

import cgi

def htmlTop():
    print("Content-type: text/html")
    print()
    print("""<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
                <head>
                        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                        <title>My Server Side Test</title>
                </head>
                <body>""")

def htmlTail():
    print("""</body>
        </html>""")

if ___name___ == "__main__":
    try:
        htmlTop()
        print("Hello World")
        htmlTail()
    except:
        cgi.print_exception()
```

Please note I have tried using `print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")` as opposed to the extra print statement.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I found the errors in your script

The first mistake I found was the quote you used when requiring python,
 so 
`#!"C:\Python33\python.exe"` should be changed to `#!C:\Python33\python.exe`

The second  mistake I found was the additional bars you used 
`There are 3 bars here->___name___<-and here`
 so 
`___name___` should be changed to `__name__`

So the final code should be

```
#!C:\Python33\python.exe

import cgi

def htmlTop():
    print("Content-type: text/html")
    print()
    print("""<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                    <title>My Server Side Test</title>
            </head>
            <body>""")

def htmlTail():
    print("""</body>
    </html>""")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        htmlTop()
        print("Hello World")
        htmlTail()
    except:
        cgi.print_exception()
```